# Check if parameter in string is followed by a specific letter - python

Tags: python, string, function

I found a similar answer for this but only in java. Here is an example of my code at the moment:

```
def find_x(phrase, target):
  i=phrase.find(target)
  if 'x' in phrase[i+1]:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

I then realized in the case the phrase is 'Texas' and the target is 'Te' the find function will only give the index of the first letter of the first occurrence of the target. Therefore when it checks if the next letter is 'x' it will be part of the target returning False instead of True. Let me know if there is a way to get around this issue, thanks!

Comment: `return target + 'x' in phrase`

Comment: While yes this does work for most cases, it checks the whole string. This does not check if only the first occurrence of the phrase has x after it.

Comment: So you're saying that if `target` occurs more than once in `phrase`, you want to know if _every occurrence_ is followed by "x"?

Comment: No, I only want to check if the first occurrence is followed by 'x'. If another occurrence has x after it, it will not return True. Thanks for the help (:

Comment: `if phrase[i+len(target)+1] == "x"` ? Could potentially fail for `IndexError` so you would need to verify that it's in bounds.

Comment: Yes there is an Index Error which still confuses me on why that occurs, I am still a beginner in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the suggestion in the comments to check for `target + 'x' in phrase`, you could just make that check and then also check that it's in the same spot as the first occurrence of `target`:

```
>>> def find_x(phrase, target):
...     return target + 'x' in phrase and phrase.find(target) == phrase.find(target + 'x')
...
>>> find_x('Texas', 'Te')
True
>>> find_x('TeTexas', 'Te')
False
```

The option of explicitly looking for the first occurrence of `target` and then checking the character immediately after it is more efficient, since it only requires one scan through `phrase`.  You just want to catch the potential `IndexError` or `ValueError` and return `False` instead of raising.

```
>>> def find_x(phrase, target):
...     try:
...         return phrase[phrase.index(target) + len(target)] == 'x'
...     except (IndexError, ValueError):
...         return False
...
>>> find_x('Texas', 'Te')
True
>>> find_x('TeTexas', 'Te')
False
>>> find_x('Te', 'Te')  # this is the case that'll raise IndexError
False
>> find_x('Texas', 'Tee')  # this is the case that'll raise ValueError
False
```